# Why this code has a runtime error using map with strings (C++)?

Tags: c++, string, stl, dictionary, printf

Why does this code has a runtime error?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
map <int, string> A;
map <int, string>::iterator it;

int main(){
    A[5]="yes";
    A[7]="no";
    it=A.lower_bound(5);
    cout<<(*it).second<<endl;    // No problem
    printf("%s\n",(*it).second); // Run-time error
    return 0;
}
```

If you use cout, it works fine; however, if you use printf it gives runtime error.
How do I correct it? Thanks!

Comment: g++ 4.6.3 complains with a compile-time "error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'struct std::basic_string<char>' through '...'".  I bet your compiler has at least a relevant warning too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're passing in a `std::string` to something that expects a `char *` (as you can see from the documentation on `printf`, which is a C function, which doesn't have classes, let alone `string`). To access a const version of the underlying `char *`, use the `c_str` function:

```
printf("%s\n",(*it).second.c_str());
```

Also, `(*it).second` is equivalent to `it->second`, but the latter is easier to type and, in my opinion, makes it clearer what's happening.

Comment: What exactly does c_str() do? P.S. great answer!

Comment: @DanielTalamas, `std::string` has a `char *` data member that it uses to store the string. `c_str()` returns a constant, null-terminated version of that, but it's only valid until the next non-const member function is called. Like the name suggests, it extracts a C-style string from a `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `c_str()`:

```
printf("%s\n",(*it).second.c_str());
```

`printf()` is expecting a C string for `%s`, and you're giving it a C++ string instead.
Since `printf()` is not typesafe, it has no way of diagnosing this (although a good compiler might warn you about this error).

Comment: What exactly does c_str() do? P.S. nice answer